# Starting with WebSockets

Tags: websocket

I had a huge confusion in WebSockets. I read some blog about WebSockets and it requires `node` websocket server, I downloaded the demo files and the chat application didn't seem to work. To summarize this, what do I need to use WebSockets? Do I need to download `node` server or something? And what is something to relate with `socket.io` to one another?

Answer (score 4):

### WebSockets?

WebSockets is a standard for implementing socket communication (to a server) over the web.

### Is node required?

Now this server which the socket communication prevails between can be implemented in any way whatsoever. Node is surely a popular option to implement the server side in however its not the only, you can use python, erlang, ruby, or any other language where you can bind a socket connection.

### What is socket.io?

socket.io is javascript library which makes it possible for **socket** OR **socket-like** connections over the web. See the WebSockets is a *recent* standard, not all browsers support it, only the modern ones do (proof: http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets). What makes socket.io so popular, rainbow and fairy tale like (and one of the main reasons why you happened to stumble upon it while researching WebSockets) is that it will make socket/socket-like communications possible in all browsers.

- **socket**: when socket.io detects a browser supporting WebSockets, in which case it uses this WebSockets implementation for the socket communications.
- **socket-like**: however when socket.io detects a browser which does NOT support WebSockets it will still provide you with socket-like communication. Tid bit: the internals of this feature use AJAX polling.

Answer (score 3):

Node is a good place to start for websockets, but by no means the only place.

I would probably start here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: Do I need to install any server side implementation? Whatever server side I choose from?