# How to refresh the web page on all user's interface when some user make changes to that page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In my PHP application every user can see the task list. When a user deletes a task I'm able to refresh a page so that they will see the new task list, but that task is still seen by other users.

What I want is when user deletes a particular task, all users should get a fresh task list (update or refresh should happen).

What is the best way to do that? I'm also using my application iphone safari browser.

Comment: Sounds like you need AJAX.

Comment: This question is asked 5 times a day, please check other questions (with useful answers) first.

Comment: @Pieter : I'm sorry but i searched on this before posting but didn't find answer.

Comment: @AmalMurali : Ajax which executes after every 5 seconds like that? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [long polling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15724055/) or [websockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336876/)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be

- Save a random string(token) on the Server and deliver it to every web page
- Inside the web page run a js-script(Ajax), which ask the Server for the token - if a new token is returned, refresh the page
- if you want to refresh all the pages, just set a new token

Comment: Do you mean token for every task?

Comment: @sach: one general token for all, change it whenever a task changed

Comment: @akram : What if two user tries to delete two different task at same time?In that case will one token work?

Comment: @sach: don't worry about that.

Comment: The important point is, to generate a new token - how often you do this, doesn't matter(as long as the tokens are random)